# Finding applicant that applied to more than 2 jobs

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to **Find the applicant who has applied to more than 2 different companies**

The applicants shown should be:

Monica (a2): jobs 101, j02, and j04

Jim (a3): jobs j02, j04, and j06

This is the script used for this!!

```
drop table Jobskills;
drop table Appskills;
drop table Applies;
drop table Applicant;
drop table Skills;
drop table Job;
drop table Company;

create table Company(compid char(5) primary key, compname varchar(20), 
                     comptype varchar(15));
create table Job(jobid char(5) primary key, jobtitle varchar(20),
                 salarylow int, salaryhigh int, location char(10), 
                 compid references Company(compid) on delete cascade);
create table Skills(skillid char(5) primary key, skillname varchar(15));
create table Jobskills(jobid references Job(jobid) on delete cascade, 
                       skillid references Skills(skillid), 
               expertiseneeded int, primary key(jobid,skillid));
create table Applicant(appid char(5) primary key, name varchar(15), 
                       age int, highdegree char(5), expected_salary int) ;
create table AppSkills(appid references Applicant(appid) on delete cascade, 
                       skillid references Skills(skillid), expertise int,
                       primary key(appid, skillid));
create table Applies(jobid references Job(jobid), 
                     appid references Applicant(appid) on delete cascade, 
                     appdate date, decisiondate date, outcome char(10),  
                     primary key(jobid, appid));

rem Initial Company data
insert into Company values('PWC', 'Price Waterhouse', 'consulting');
insert into Company values('MSFT', 'Microsoft', 'software');
insert into Company values('INTL', 'Intel', 'electronics');
insert into Company values('NCR', 'NCR Corp', 'server');
insert into Company values('WPAF', 'WP Air Force', 'defense');
insert into Company values('DLT', 'Deloitte', 'consulting');

rem Initial Job data
insert into Job values('101', 'Programmer', 55000, 60000, 'Redmond', 'MSFT');
insert into Job values('j02', 'Designer', 42000, 45000, 'Redmond', 'MSFT');
insert into Job values('j03', 'SAP impl', 30000, 40000, 'Chicago', 'PWC');
insert into Job values('j04', 'Proj mgmt', 35000, 55000, 'Chicago', 'PWC');
insert into Job values('j05', 'SOX', 60000, 65000, 'Detroit', 'PWC');
insert into Job values('j06', 'db admin', 45000, 50000, 'Dayton', 'NCR');
insert into Job values('j07', 'db designer', 35000, 40000, 'Dayton', 'NCR');
insert into Job values('j08', 'intern', 25000, 28000, 'Dayton', 'NCR');
insert into Job values('j09', 'engineer', 52000, 55000, 'Dayton','WPAF');
insert into Job values('j10', 'dba', 62000, 65000, 'Dayton','WPAF');
insert into Job values('j11', 'hardware dev', 50000, 65000, 'NYC','INTL');
insert into Job values('j12', 'pcb designer', 55000, 68000,'NYC','INTL');
insert into Job values('j13', 'chip designer', 40000, 55000,'Chicago','INTL');
insert into Job values('j14', 'IT', 40000, 60000, 'Dayton', 'DLT');
insert into Job values('j15', 'IT', 50000, 70000, 'Chicago', 'DLT');

rem initial Skills data
insert into Skills values('s1', 'database');
insert into Skills values('s2', 'programming');
insert into Skills values('s3', 'sox');
insert into Skills values('s4', 'project');
insert into Skills values('s5', 'hardware');
insert into Skills values('s6', 'sap');
insert into Skills values('s7', 'analysis');

rem Initial Jobskills data
insert into Jobskills values('101', 's2', 5);
insert into Jobskills values('101', 's7', 4);
insert into Jobskills values('j02', 's2', 3);
insert into Jobskills values('j02', 's7', 5);
insert into Jobskills values('j03', 's6', 5);
insert into Jobskills values('j04', 's7', 4);
insert into Jobskills values('j04', 's4', 5);
insert into Jobskills values('j04', 's2', 2);
insert into Jobskills values('j05', 's3', 5);
insert into Jobskills values('j06', 's1', 5);
insert into Jobskills values('j06', 's2', 3);
insert into Jobskills values('j07', 's1', 4);
insert into Jobskills values('j07', 's7', 3);
insert into Jobskills values('j08', 's1', 2);
insert into Jobskills values('j09', 's2', 4);
insert into Jobskills values('j09', 's4', 4);
insert into Jobskills values('j10', 's4', 3);
insert into Jobskills values('j10', 's1', 5);
insert into Jobskills values('j11', 's5', 3);
insert into Jobskills values('j11', 's4', 3);
insert into Jobskills values('j12', 's5', 5);
insert into Jobskills values('j13', 's1', 4);
insert into Jobskills values('j13', 's2', 5);
insert into Jobskills values('j14', 's7', 4);

rem initial Applicants data
insert into Applicant values('a1', 'Joe', 30, 'MS', 55000);
insert into Applicant values('a2', 'Monica', 25, 'BS', 62000);
insert into Applicant values('a3', 'Jim', 22, 'BS', 45000);
insert into Applicant values('a4', 'Monica', 25, 'BS', 34000);

rem initial Appskills data
insert into Appskills values('a1', 's1', 3);
insert into Appskills values('a1', 's2', 4);
insert into Appskills values('a1', 's4', 4);
insert into Appskills values('a1', 's6', 3);
insert into Appskills values('a1', 's7', 4);
insert into Appskills values('a2', 's2', 3);
insert into Appskills values('a2', 's3', 5);
insert into Appskills values('a2', 's6', 4);
insert into Appskills values('a3', 's4', 3);
insert into Appskills values('a3', 's1', 3);
insert into Appskills values('a3', 's2', 5);

rem Applies
insert into Applies values ('101', 'a1', '01-JAN-06', '08-JAN-06', 'hire');
insert into Applies values ('101', 'a2', '01-JAN-06', '08-JAN-06', 'hire');
insert into Applies values ('j02', 'a2', '01-JAN-06', '08-JAN-06', 'hire');
insert into Applies values ('j04', 'a2', '01-JAN-06', '08-JAN-06', 'hire');
insert into Applies values ('j02', 'a3', '01-JAN-06', '08-JAN-06', 'nohire');
insert into Applies values ('j04', 'a3', '01-JAN-06', '08-JAN-06', 'nohire');
insert into Applies values ('j06', 'a3', '01-JAN-06', '08-JAN-06', 'nohire');
```

*This is my code so far...*

```
SELECT app.name, app.appid, j.jobid, c.compname
FROM applicant app INNER JOIN applies apps ON app.appid = apps.appid INNER JOIN 
job j ON j.jobid = apps.jobid INNER JOIN company c ON c.compid = j.compid
WHERE apps.appid > '2'
```

Something is wrong though because I get Joe (a1) and I should not be getting him. I should only be getting Monica (a2) and Jim (a3). What am I missing?

Comment: What is the _business logic_ that differentiates between who is selected and who is  not selected.

Comment: @EdStevens The difference is that applicant a3 did not get hired, but both applicants a2 and a3 applied to 3 jobs total so they should appear?

Comment: No, you need to explain the business rules to determine who you select. The business purpose of the report.  The closest you've come is "Find the applicant who has applied to more than 2 different companies".  What about applicant with 2 or more apllications, but to the same company?   Do you want to report only those who were ultimately hired, or anyone who meets the 'number of applications' requirement?  IF only those ultimately hired, is there any connection between their being hired and any particular application - ie: applied 3 times, hired once, vs. applied 3 times, hired all three?

Comment: @EdStevens It does not matter if they were hired or not hired, but rather that the applicant submitted to more than 2 different companies. So, I am looking to find anyone who meets the number of applicants submitted to different companies.

Comment: Ok.  Does @Gordon Linoff answer do it?  I was just trying to get you to clarify the requirement, so that those better than me at complex sql could better understand the problem.

Comment: @EdStevens It didn't work for me - Oracle kept giving me errors. But I think I figured it out anyway :) Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Hmmm . . . You need aggregation.  To answer your question, you only need a `HAVING` clause and the job and companies are not important.  But you can put them into delimited strings if you like:

```
SELECT app.name, app.appid,
       LIST_AGG(j.jobid, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY j.jobid), 
       LIST_AGG(c.compname, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY c.compname)
FROM applicant app INNER JOIN
     applies apps
     ON app.appid = apps.appid INNER JOIN 
     job j
     ON j.jobid = apps.jobid INNER JOIN
     company c
     ON c.compid = j.compid
GROUP BY app.name, app.id, 
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT c.compname) > 2;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here in common table expression I have ranked the unique university names for an applicant . Then with exists I have counted only applicants with more than one university count and showed information for those applicants only.

```
with cte as (
SELECT app.name, app.appid, j.jobid, c.compname, dense_rank()over(partition by app.appid order by compname)companycount
FROM applicant app INNER JOIN applies apps ON app.appid = apps.appid INNER JOIN 
job j ON j.jobid = apps.jobid INNER JOIN company c ON c.compid = j.compid)
select name,appid,jobid,compname from cte c
where exists (select appid from cte ct where ct.companycount>1 and c.appid=ct.appid)
```